# Как работать с большим дампом данных JSON

Tags: база-данных, json, api, big-data, dump

Есть дамп отелей размером 13гб, в формате JSON.

**Вопрос:** как работать с этим дампом, если даже редактор затрудняется открыть его?

**Задача такая:** нужно реализовать систему поиска туров по дампу, которую предоставляет [API](https://docs.emergingtravel.com/#0b55c99a-7ef0-4a18-bbfe-fd1bdf35d08e)

*Буду рад любому совету в этом направлении. :)*

Comment: RapidJSON имеет сакс [интерфейс](https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_sax.html), если C++ устроит. Не требует загрузки всего json в память, и один из самых быстрых в голактике.

Comment: Как часто меняется дамп? В принципе можно распарсить любым инструментом и сложить в обычную реляционную базу.